# Excel/VBA: link cells from column in Row

Tags: excel, vba

On page 1 I have the following:
B1: Name
C1: Date
D1: Currency
E1: Reference

On Page 2: I have 3 different possible versions of datasets:
Version 1:

A3: Name
A6: Date
A9: Currency
A10: Reference

Version 2:

A1: Name
A5: Date
A9: Currency
A10: Reference

Version 3:
A2: Name
A3: Date
A4: Currency
A5: Reference

I would like to specify on Page 1 i.e. in cell A2 which Version applies.
if i.e. the row 2 should be linked to version 3 it should take:

A2: 3 (Version)
B2: link to A2 page 2
C2: link to A3 page 2
D2: link to A4 page 2
E2: link to A5 page 3

if 
A2: 2 (Version)
B2: link to A1 page 2
C2: link to A5 page 2
D2: link to A9 page 2
E2: link to A10 page 3

etc.

NOW in Row 3 on Page 1:
it should take whats in  column B on page 2

i.e.
A3: 2 (Version)
B3: link to B1 page 2
C3: link to B5 page 2
D3: link to B9 page 2
E3: link to B10 page 3

etc.

in Row 4 on page 1 it should take whats in column C on page 2.

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to write shorter questions.

Comment: *How can i do that?* I suggest formulas or an UDF... if you get problems with doing that, then come back and show some code we can check for errors...

Comment: Would certain cells be empty in the different versions? It would be important to know if there was a consistent difference between the versions to work out which version it was.